# How to create an Entry renderer in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I want to create a renderer for an entry field using Xamarin. What is the best way to get it? I have no idea how to get it, any help will be appreciate.

This is my entry field and I want to create font size renderer for that

```
<Entry x:Name="txtTest"/>
```

Comment: There is a great walkthrough on the documentation page: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

Comment: Add more details to your question, fast! There is a close vote.

Answer (score 0):

This is sample of Entry that set padding to 0 and can set TextSize property.

```
namespace projectname
{
    public class BareEntry : Entry
    {
        public BareEntry ()
        {
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty TextSizeProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create<BareEntry,int> (X => X.TextSize, 10);

        public int TextSize
        {
            get {return (int)base.GetValue (TextSizeProperty);}
            set {base.SetValue (TextSizeProperty, value);}
        }
    }
}
```

This part is on android platform

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using projectname;
using projectname.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using MocMSearch.Droid;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (BareEntry), typeof (BareEntryRenderer))]
namespace MocMSearch.Droid
{
    public class BareEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public BareEntryRenderer ()
        {
        }
         protected override void     OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Entry> e)

        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Recreate ();
        }
        void Recreate()
        {

            if (this.Control == null) return;
            Control.SetPadding (0,0,0,0);

            Control.SetTextSize (Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Mm,(Element as BareEntry).TextSize);
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged (sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "TextSize") 
            {
                Recreate ();
                this.Invalidate ();
            }

        }

    }
}
```